# Unable to add Plugin to Cordova Project 3.1 for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to add 'device' plugin to my project and it is failing.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device --verbose
```

and I get following log:

```
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "org.apache.cordova.device"
Fetching plugin from location "org.apache.cordova.device"...
Error: Error fetching plugin: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

I don't understand whats the problem.
Do I have to add 'local'?I tried but cordova does not understand local.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you in the directory where you added the platform i.e android?

Comment: Yes.I even tried going into Plugins directory and tried but in vain.

Comment: Have you tried with other plugin? is it successfully added?

Comment: Yes git command line tool is required before adding the plugin. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cordova adding plugin using command line tool**

Before adding plugins to your application **git command line tool** is required.

You could download and install git command line for Mac OS X in [Git For Mac](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.3.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg&can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded). For windows, Download Git on [For Winows](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Then: git clone git://project.url.here

Comment: Yes its working now after installing git.The error happened as the path was not properly set for git.Thank you.